# MySQL REGEX to convert json to comma separated keys to use in WHERE IN

Tags: mysql, regex

I have some columns `VARCHAR` which contains JSON content with relation to other rows of the same table, and i need to convert this into comma separated keys to use a WHERE IN.

Example column content:

`[{"manuel":"Manuel Fernandez"},{"marta":"Marta Flores"}]`

And what i need is:

`manuel,marta`

This is part of a bigger query where this conversion should be applied to more than one column and thats why i think the best solution is doing this using Mysql `REGEX`

**Update 1**

Mysql version `5.7.25`

Comment: You can't use `WHERE IN` with a comma-delimited string, you have to use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? You need 8.0 to be able to do `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Comment: @Barmar I have MySQL 5.7.25

Comment: That info would be quite easy to retrieve from a regular RDBMS layout.  Is there some overriding reason to store as JSON in the first place?

Comment: @RickJames unfortunately this is a legacy system and i cant modify the table structure :/ a simple id relation table will be simple and great for this scenario :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `[`, `]`, `{"`, and everything from `":"` to the next `}` from the string.

```
regexp_replace(columnName, '\\[|\\]|\\{"|":"[^}]*\\}', '')
```

You need MySQL 8.0 to get a built-in `REGEXP_REPLACE()` function. If you're using an older version, see [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)